# ggplot2 - removing size legend in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove the size 20 legend on the right. Below is my code:

```
qplot(lingLocation[ind,ind_water_fountain]/lingLocation[ind,1], 
     lingLocation[ind,ind_soda]/lingLocation[ind,1],
     color = lingLocation[ind,ind_frosting]/lingLocation[ind,1], size = 20) +
     # opts(legend.position = "none") +
     scale_colour_gradient("Frosting %", low = "blue", high = "red") +
     ylab("Soda %") +
     xlab("Water Fountain %")
```

Thanks!

[image: my plot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `size=20` argument from the `qplot` call, and stick it in a `geom_point` call.

For example, change your code to this:

```
qplot(lingLocation[ind,ind_water_fountain]/lingLocation[ind,1], 
     lingLocation[ind,ind_soda]/lingLocation[ind,1],
     color = lingLocation[ind,ind_frosting]/lingLocation[ind,1]) +
     # opts(legend.position = "none") +
     scale_colour_gradient("Frosting %", low = "blue", high = "red") +
     ylab("Soda %") +
     xlab("Water Fountain %") +
     geom_point(size=20)
```

I don't use the `qplot` function, but I think that should work. I believe `ggplot2` adds a scale for every aesthetic call in each geom, which is what `qplot` is probably doing. But since you are applying the size to all points, having the size parameter outside of the `aes` should achieve the same effect, and the `size=20` will not generate a legend for it (I think). And `geom_point` should inherit the aesthetics from `qplot` (I hope).

Let me know if this works!

EDIT:

I just tested it. Placing size inside `geom_point` should work. However, the size settings from inside `qplot` seem to differ from the size settings when called from `geom_point`, so maybe setting a smaller size inside `geom_point` should do the trick (say, `geom_point(size=5)`)

Answer (score 3):

`qplot` assumes that the `size` specification is a mapping and so creates a scale. Here, you just want to set it to 20, so replace `size = 20` with `size = I(20)`. That sets the size and does not create a scale (and probably makes the points bigger than you anticipated).